# Can't hide loading image

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

In my jsp page.. I am displaying table dynamically using jquery.
Everything is fine but now the image/text used to show until page ready is not getting hidden even after I displayed table. 
What's the problem?/

Here is my code:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>DbRefresh Sample</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var url="/DbRefresh/FetchRecords";
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#loading').hide();
 //$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
 setInterval(callUrl,15000);
 function callUrl()
 {
  //alert("Called");
  $.ajax({
   url:'/DbRefresh/FetchRecords',  
         type:'post',  
         dataType: 'json',
         cache: false,
         contentType: 'application/json',
         success: function(data) {
             $("tr td").remove();
             $.each(data.obj,function(index,obj)
                     {
    $("#table").append('<tr><td>'+obj.name+'</td><td>'+obj.age+'</td></tr>');
     })
                //$("tr td").replacewith(tabdata);
       } 
   });
  }
});

</script>
<style type="text/css">
#loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
}

#loading-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 100;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="table">
<table border='4' cellpadding='6' cellspacing='3' width='300px'>
<thead><tr bgcolor='66FF00'><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr></thead>
</table>
</div>
<img id="loading-image" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no tag with "loading" id

so make it like

```
$('#loading-image').hide();
```

Comment: please read other answers too... they are precious then this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : first of all correct the `id` of loading image. First show it by default and then hide it as soon as AJAX call completes and just before loading table.

```
<script>
var url="/DbRefresh/FetchRecords";
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$('#loading-image').hide();//remove from here
    //$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    setInterval(callUrl,15000);
    function callUrl()
    {
        //alert("Called");
        $.ajax({
            url:'/DbRefresh/FetchRecords',  
            type:'post',  
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) {
                $("tr td").remove();
                //hide loading image 
                $('#loading-image').hide();
                $.each(data.obj,function(index,obj)
                        {
                $("#table").append('<tr><td>'+obj.name+'</td><td>'+obj.age+'</td></tr>');
                    })
                   //$("tr td").replacewith(tabdata);
                } 
            });
        }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your img tag id is `loading-image`

And you use it in jQuery as `$('#loading').hide();`

Chang `$('#loading').hide();` to `$('#loading-image').hide();`

And place it in to `callUrl()` function before `$.ajax()` call.